# Codeigniter disallowed characters workaround

Tags: php, codeigniter, escaping, special-characters, codeigniter-url

I have already checked quite a few other answers but to no avail.

I have been hired to fix bugs for a job that some other developer ran away from.
The application has a add comment and delete comment functionality.

The problem comes in the delete comment part. He designed the database such that all comments are simply entered into a single cell separated by pipe characters. So while deleting a comment, **the entire comment needs to be placed in the url as a parameter** which is then passed to the model and removed from the database.

I do know this is bad, but I cannot recode the entire functionality.

**Now, when a user enters a comment such as "What's Up?", the delete comment url throws the "Codeigniter: The URI you submitted has disallowed characters." error.**

I tried converting the quotes to HTML character entities but they again contain disallowed characters.

Can anybody please suggest a possible workaround for this problem?
Redesigning the database is not a viable option as I'll then have to change the extensive php code used for handling the different delimiters.
Messing with the disallowed characters list also seems to be a bad idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if `htmlentities` will help.
Did you first call `urlencode` on just the parameters?

```
<?php

$query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode("What's Up?");
echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';

?>
```

`<a href="mycgi?foo=What%27s+Up%3F">`

Also check if you need to add escape characters to any of these if they are treated as special characters by the database.

e.g. If % is treated as special character, then you may need to add a `\` before it.

Comment: Yes that worked!! had to play around with the functions a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Open your config file and find this parameter:

> $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_()@&-!=?';

You can change it according to your requirement ​or you can leave it blank.
Read the comment section in config file.

It says that: `Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.`

Comment: I did mention in my question that messing with this config might be a bad idea. Any other workaround?

Comment: it is a codeigniter's config file. If you add new character into `permitted_uri_chars` parameter, it will not affect your old coding. it just allows character in URL.

Comment: The application already shows signs of bad coding practices. If I allow single quote characters in the url, won't it open up doors for sql injection attempts.

Comment: in that case use `rawurlencode` method to encrypt URL and allow it's related character into `permitted_uri_chars` parameter.

Comment: Yes, I did something similar. Used a chain of urlencode/urldecode and allowed "+" character in the config.